# Android google translate API

Tags: android, google-api, translate

I have a problem with receiving translations from Google via translate API. Does somebody know what is wrong? Thanks!

Note:
It has worked fine for some time but maybe 5 months ago it stopped to work.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    GoogleAPI.setHttpReferrer("http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/");
    GoogleAPI.setKey("xxx");

    try {
        tv_answer.setText(Translate.DEFAULT.execute(tv_source.getText().toString(), Language.CZECH, Language.ENGLISH));
    } catch (GoogleAPIException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Received error:

```
com.google.api.GoogleAPIException: java.lang.Exception: [google-api-translate-java] Error retrieving translation.
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem only appears on android when using this api client. I believe this is because this api client is old and/or poorly written.

You can attempt to get the source code from [here](https://github.com/richmidwinter/google-api-translate-java) and fix the problem yourself, or just use the api directly from Java using GET with HttpURLConnection and them parse the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Google Translate API is a paid service.

**Note:**

(https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started)

Comment: yes, I know. My credit card is linked to the Google Api's and Google translate API is ON in console.

Comment: Set your DNS to google one

if on linux machine

sudo gedit /etc/resolv.conf

add

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
or if on windows goto network setting and set DNS for active connection